# Why do I get "Avoid mutating a prop directly" when using NumericTextField?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have created a simple view component in VueJS and I'm getting a pretty common error:

> void mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "value"

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <numeric-text-field class="mx-auto" label="Head Mass" units="kg" v-model="turbine.head_mass" />
</template>

<script>
import NumericTextField from '@/components/common/NumericTextField'
export default {
  name: 'Turbines',
  components: {
    NumericTextField
  },
  data () {
    return {
      turbine: {}
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Oddly enough I get the error for modifying "value" but I don't have value in my code. I think this is caused by the indirection layer created by the numeric-text-field. This problem does not exist in my code when I use only normal input text. What is going on here? Is there another special way I'm supposed to hook up the model to my numeric-text-fields other than v-model?

Comment: `this.$emit('input', value)` from the `NumericTextField` component in `@change`. Do not directly modify the value being passed to you, as it's a property at that point. If you want `2-way` binding use the `sync` modifier.

Comment: Just show your NumericTextField.vue, and I sure, there will be something like `<input type="number" v-model="value" />`. And `props` with `value`

Comment: Oh geez, this was correct from both Ohgodwhy and Alexander Yakushev. I didn't realize NumericTextField was non-standard, and part of the code base my partner had added in. Otherwise I would have read through that. It was, also, not properly implemented in exactly the way you predicted. I did some reading and eventually added the emit and @input (not @change) suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be, unbeknownst to me upon original posting, and issue in NumericTextField. I thought that was a standard Vueify component but was added by a coworker. It did not properly handle bidirectional input as pointed out by the comments on the original post.

The trick is to add this.$emit('input', value) from the NumericTextField component in @input like Ohgodwhy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand how props work in Vue. The key aspect here is that props are utilized for [one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). If you want it to be two-way data flow, you need to instead use `v-model`.

Having said that, there are a few different ways that you could go about doing this. I prefer to utilize [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) for stuff like this! It's pretty clean, and easy to follow in the code.

Instead of modifying the prop directly, in your `numeric-text-field` component, you should instead emit an event when the
value is changed. This is how your `Turbines.vue` would look:

```
<template>
    <numeric-text-field class="mx-auto"
    label="Head Mass"
    units="kg"
    :headMass="turbine.head_mass"
    v-on:updateHeadMass="updateHeadMass"/>
</template>

<script>
import NumericTextField from '@/components/common/NumericTextField'
export default {
  name: 'Turbines',
  components: {
    NumericTextField
  },
  data () {
    return {
      // You should consider initializing your data with the structure that matches what you expect, instead of an empty object
      turbine: {
        head_mass: ""
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateHeadMass(value) {
      this.turbines.head_mass = value;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

You'll notice the `v-on:updateHeadMass` attribute. This is how we listen for emitted events from our child components. When the `updateHeadMass` even is emitted, we can call a specific function and update our data in the parent component accordingly. This will cause a reactive change in the child component, which is then updated.

**Inside NumericTextField**

Instead of modifying the prop directly, use a computed property, which emits an event, up to the parent component when the input is changed
This is how your `NumericTextField` component could look:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="headMass">Head Mass</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="localHeadMass"  name="headMass"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "numeric-text-field",
  computed: {
    localHeadMass: {
      get() {
        return this.headMass;
      },
      set(value) {
        // Now, anytime we change this property, our parent receives the new value and updates the `headMass` prop!
        this.$emit("updateHeadMass", value);
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    headMass: {
      type: String,
      default: "0",
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

If you don't care for the above approach, you could instead use a watcher like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="headMass">Head Mass</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="localHeadMass" v-on:change="updateHeadMass" name="headMass"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "numeric-text-field",
  data: () => {
    return {
      localHeadMass: ""
    };
  },
  props: {
    headMass: {
      type: String,
      default: "0",
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateHeadMass() {
      this.$emit("updateHeadMass", this.localHeadMass);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    headMass(value) {
      this.localHeadMass = value;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```